# two submit buttons in one form of type 'image'

Tags: php, html

I have a form in PHP with two submit buttons of type 'image'.
How do I know which button is clicked?

Code:

```
<?php

echo ("

    <form action='WijzigSession.php' method='POST'>
    <td><input class= 'nummers' type='number' name='aantal' value=".$_SESSION['producten'][$i]['aantal']." min='1' max='20'>
    <input name='refresh' class='buttons' type='image' src='img/refresh.png'</a>
    <input name='delete' class='buttons' type='image' src='img/delete.png'</a>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$i'>
    </form></td>
    <td>&euro; ".$_SESSION['producten'][$i]['prijs']."</td>

    ");

?>
```

Comment: do you want to check on server side or client side...if server side $_POST['buttonName'] == refresh or $_POST['buttonName'] == delete

Comment: You can add a name and value to your "buttons", whose values you can access in php with $_POST["Name"] = "Value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
if(isset($_POST['refresh_x'])) { //you can potentially even check for '$_POST['refresh_y']'
    // refresh is clicked
}

if(isset($_POST['delete_x'])) {
    // delete is clicked
}
```

Comment: Why the '_x' behind the name?

Comment: that's the use of posting via image. Whenever you post via an image  the x/y coordinates that were clicked on are posted. Eg: $_POST['refresh_x'] refers the x-coordinate of image in refresh button